# What is the last grpcio version to support Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, grpc, grpc-python

The company I'm working for is still in the process of going over from Python 2.7 to Python 3, so I'm stuck with Python 2.7 even though it is officially already end of life.

For a project I'm looking into grpc, but I see that the latest versions do not support Python 2.7 anymore.
But since I'm stuck with Python 2.7 my question is simple: what is the latest version of grpcio which still supports Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the supported version in PyPI pages. On the bottom left corner, if there is a "2.7" tag in the "Classifiers" section, that means 2.7 is supported. Using this method, we can find the latest `grpcio` version for 2.7 to be `v1.39.0`: https://pypi.org/project/grpcio/1.39.0/

Comment: Thanks. For some reason pip installed 1.41 on my ubuntu22+python2.7 and it created grpc segmentation fault